Is there a way to calculate the equivalent constant engine torque from the torque graph other than using the empiric way?
I have some online car and moto transmission calculators and comparators that simulate the acceleration times etc.
After many years of trying to find a replacement for max power to characterize the engine with a single value of torque that is more precise than power, I defined the Weighted average torque. But using it in the simulation did not confirm it as an equivalent (using that torque instead of the engine torque curve did not result in the same distance covered in the same time while using a single gear ratio on all rpm range).
Then I tried the empiric way and noticed there is an Equivalent constant engine torque that fulfills that condition as it can be seen in this video.
I did not had the necessary mathematical skills to define a way to calculate it rather than finding it with multiple simulation tries.
Can it be calculated (and how)?
I will not get into more details for now because there are many, but I will gladly reply if any questions arise.
UPDATE:
Please read all comments and analyze the links before posting so we can keep the discussion on point. This is not a question about power, nor a discussion about it. It is only about torque. Why torque and not power is another discussion that for me started in 2017 and will go on many years in the future (sadly) ...
UPDATE 2
Gear ratio 9.820:

Gear ratio 10:

Input data for last picture (the above last one):

{"calcinputname":"Tesla SP 600Nm - web info ~265.51Nm 10","valuea":"245","valueb":"45","valuea1":"","valueb1":"","valuec":"19","valuec1":"","rap1":"1","rap2":"1","rap3":"1","rap4":"1","rap5":"1","rap6":"1","rapf":"10","Pmax":"311","PRPM":"8709","Mmax":"599","MRPM":"4952","M":"2112","schimb1":"15435","schimb2":"15435","schimb3":"15435","schimb4":"15435","schimb5":"15435","RPMNm1":"1350","NmRPM1":"600","RPMNm2":"4952.36","NmRPM2":"599.06","RPMNm3":"5080.59","NmRPM3":"590.64","RPMNm4":"5970.07","NmRPM4":"500.78","RPMNm5":"6681.05","NmRPM5":"447.42","RPMNm6":"7599.41","NmRPM6":"394.07","RPMNm7":"8695.51","NmRPM7":"344.46","RPMNm8":"9213.94","NmRPM8":"306.08","RPMNm9":"9821.24","NmRPM9":"269.58","RPMNm10":"10443.36","NmRPM10":"238.69","RPMNm11":"11169.16","NmRPM11":"207.8","RPMNm12":"11865.33","NmRPM12":"184.4","RPMNm13":"12902.19","NmRPM13":"156.32","RPMNm14":"14101.98","NmRPM14":"131.05","RPMNm15":"15435","NmRPM15":"109.52","airdensity":"1.225","refarea":"2.53","dragcoeff":""}
vs
{"calcinputname":"Tesla SP 600Nm - web info EQ 392Nm 10 ratio","valuea":"245","valueb":"45","valuea1":"","valueb1":"","valuec":"19","valuec1":"","rap1":"1","rap2":"1","rap3":"1","rap4":"1","rap5":"1","rap6":"1","rapf":"10","Pmax":"311","PRPM":"8709","Mmax":"599","MRPM":"4952","M":"2112","schimb1":"15435","schimb2":"15435","schimb3":"15435","schimb4":"15435","schimb5":"15435","RPMNm1":"1350","NmRPM1":"392","RPMNm2":"4952.36","NmRPM2":"392","RPMNm3":"5080.59","NmRPM3":"392","RPMNm4":"5970.07","NmRPM4":"392","RPMNm5":"6681.05","NmRPM5":"392","RPMNm6":"7599.41","NmRPM6":"392","RPMNm7":"8695.51","NmRPM7":"392","RPMNm8":"9213.94","NmRPM8":"392","RPMNm9":"9821.24","NmRPM9":"392","RPMNm10":"10443.36","NmRPM10":"392","RPMNm11":"11169.16","NmRPM11":"392","RPMNm12":"11865.33","NmRPM12":"392","RPMNm13":"12902.19","NmRPM13":"392","RPMNm14":"14101.98","NmRPM14":"392","RPMNm15":"15435","NmRPM15":"392","airdensity":"1.225","refarea":"2.53","dragcoeff":""}
Analog is valid for different masses.
ANSWER:
I ended up implementing 2nd solution (not so accurate as first one but simpler to code):

Edit 2: Alternative way to get the info using only one simulation.
There is a way to find all the information you need using only one
simulation.
using the simulation, find min speed, max speed, time taken, distance traveled, as well as torque and acceleration at minimum RPM.

In this case, torque at minimum RPM = 600Nm, and acceleration (found
in the second graph) is 7.93N/kg = 7.93m/s^2. Call these values minS,
maxS, t1, d1, T, A, respectively.
We can compute t2 = (maxS - minS)/(A/T * 100).

Then compute d2 = (maxS + minS)/2 * t2.

Then, just use the formula torque = 100 * (d2 - maxS*t2)/(d1 - t1*maxS) as explained earlier.

Overall, this is the closed form formula:
100 * ((maxS + minS)/2 * (maxS - minS)/(A/T * 100) - maxS*(maxS -
minS)/(A/T * 100))/(d1 - t1*maxS)
It is very ugly, but at least you can cancel out the 100s, and you
just get:
torque = ((maxS + minS)/2 * (maxS - minS)/(A/T) - maxS*(maxS - minS)/(A/T))/(d1 - t1*maxS)

This gave 391.53 Nm so it is acceptable.
Thank you @ChickenCoding123

And to answer you, this is the reason for this: one value comparison - note that 6 gears EQT for Audi is 389.3 vs 1 gear EQT 348.77 Nm

(Full list of examples can be seen in the home page of the calculator - interesting study)
Result without air friction:

I started this journey to understand power in 2015, and now, after 9 years it is complete.
There is now a replacement for max power in engines' regard: THE EQUIVALENT CONSTANT ENGINE TORQUE!

I doubt that is a useful metric since if you change the gear ratio you'd need a different single figure torque. If your vehicle model doesn't show that effect then it is not a very good model. How good is your model of the diff?

...and how do you determine the rpm over which you 'average'?

@GregLocock you are right. This is usefull for electric cars that have 1 gear ratio. It can be determined for multiple gear ratios cars also but then it would depend on the rpm change values.

@GregLocock the target is to replace the max power (energy rate) with a torque value that reflects maximum acceleration (or minimum time for accelerating to top speed).

Any average torque isn't as useful as power because it ignores rpm.  It would make you think that diesel engines were faster than gas engines.

@TigerGuy Power is useless in mecanics because you have to convert it to torque using rotational speed to mean something in force-acceleration-movement regard. It is useful in electrical engineering only to avoid burnong the wires.  see https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=QXc4WqZgoJc and https://marius-ciclistu.ro/pdf/The%20power%E2%80%99s%20mislead%20in%20thermal%20engine%E2%80%99s%20regard.pdf

@TigerGuy sorry for the typos. PS. Even in Electrical engineering, intensity is responsible for burning the wires, not power. The only usefulness for power that I found is related to fuel consumption.

@marius-ciclistu power is best for internal combustion engines because it is independent of gearing.  Torque only confuses people, like it makes people think diesel engines are better than they really are.  People say "Oh, so much torque it pulls like a train!" Well, yes like a train in that it accelerates rather slowly, and you need a ton of gears because it revs so low.  Yes you have to concert it to get acceleration, but it's a simple conversion, and the conversion is different in every gear.

@TigerGuy Since 2017 I'm receiving arguments like yours from people, teachers etc. and only a hand full of people understand what I'm talking about. I invite you to read the pdf from the link above that I posted and then to use and UNDERSTAND the calculator/comparator/simulator from here https://marius-ciclistu.ro/cartransmissioncalculator.php. It will take you at least a full day with small pauses, so if you reply sooner than that, please excuse me if I will not reply. Best Regards. PS. There is an embedded playlist with demo videos in the transmission calculator page. Those might help.

Although I think this is a waste of time, it seems to me that given a vehicle resistance curve and a traction force at the wheel (I wasn't joking about the diff by the way, they are hard to model) you can work out the acceleration time or distance, and then use gradient descent find an equivalent constant traction force, to give the same time or distance, and then turn it into a motor torque. But you can't get both time and distance to match, except in trivial cases.

@GregLocock the resistive forces do not enter in this calculation as this would be a characteristic for the engine not for the car. If you follow the video I changed the weight of the car and the result is not affected. Same is valid for changing the gear ratio.  You can get both time and distance to fuzzy match as you see in the video with the mention that in one of the scenarios, the car will go at constant max speed for the last part of the journey ( see the gold colored line from graph 6 in the video).

@GregLocock I modeled the traction force that takes into account air friction (the diff you mention ) based on speed and the engine torque curve, gears, frontal area, drag coefficient etc. But that is not the purpose of this question. You can see it if you play around with the calculator.

@GregLocock PS. The loses from the engine (and or drive train) are included or should be included in the torque curve.

Shrugs, I've been doing this stuff for 48 years. If you change the vehicle model other than mass then your single equivalent torque value should change.

@GregLocock To get the same time and distance between the 2 models yes. But here I talk about the engine not the car/model. So changing the mass or gear ratio will result in different time and distance between models/cars with the same equivalent torque value BUT between torque graph and equivalent constant torque the time and distance will remain approx. the same. 4 calculations are in discussion here, 2 with normal torque curve and 2 with equivalent constant torque. Each pair of 2 for a weight and gear ratio will have the "same" time and distance.

@GregLocock I updated the question with an example for gear ratio 10 and 9.820. Please see the pictures. The time and distance differ between the 2 cases but within the same picture they are the same for normal and EQ calculation (see legend and look at the name).

Edit: if you don't want to read the entire explanation, just scroll to the bottom of the answer where I have a simple 3 step way to calculate this torque value.
alright so this thing is very confusing. If you look at the screenshots you have posted of the graphs of distance against time, one of the curves is extended with a brown line. To make this clear, I have magnified it in the graph below. Note that this is the exact same screenshot that you posted in your question. I have simply magnified the place where the blue curve is being extended via a brown curve.

Basically, over here, maximum RPM has already been reached, and the brown line maintains this RPM until the other curve finishes. It's not hard to see that there is always a constant torque which would allow both curves to meet at the same time and distance but I'm really skeptical about the usefulness of this value. Nonetheless, I will try to find this torque value.
Using the simulation, we can easily find the time taken to reach max RPM, the distance travelled during this time, and the maximum speed of the car. In this case, time taken is 15.09s, distance travelled is 603.76m, and maximum speed is 208kph = 57.78m/s.
Now, its obvious that the brown extension line has a gradient of 57.78. So if you just pretend to extend that brown line all the way to the x-axis, then our aim is just to find a torque value which ends somewhere on that brown line. To do this, first lets find the equation of that brown line, so lets use point-gradient equation: y - y1 = m(x - x1). we know m = 57.78, y1 = 603.76, and x1 = 15.09, so we get the brown line equation:
y - 603.76 = 57.78(x - 15.09).
Next observation to make is that when we multiply the torque by some value P, then both time taken, and distance travelled get multiplied by 1/P. So first, im going to substitute some random value for torque (lets say 100Nm), and see what I get. For a torque of 100Nm, using the simulator, I get distance travelled = 1254.83m, and time taken = 39.90s. This means that a torque of 100P results in distance travelled = 1254.83/P meters, and 39.90/P seconds. Now, we just plug 1254.83/P into y, and 39.90/P into x. So we get:
1254.83/P - 603.76 = 57.78(39.90/P - 15.09).
This is a very simple equation which I will just plug into https://www.wolframalpha.com/ and solve for P, and if you do it yourself you will see that it gives P = 3.918. And since torque = 100P, we get torque = 100 * 3.918 = 391.8Nm. Actual answer is 392Nm but that is a very small error. I will just summarise the algorithm below for simplicity. I have done some more algebra to make a closed form formula for you.

using the simulation, find maximum speed in meters per second, time taken, and distance travelled using the simulation. Call it m, t1, d1, respectively.

using the simulation, find the time taken and distance travelled for torque = 100Nm. Call it t2, and d2 respectively.

your final value for torque will be 100 * (d2 - m*t2)/(d1 - t1*m)


Please do ask if you have any questions.
Edit 2: Alternative way to get the info using only one simulation.
There is a way to find all the information you need using only one simulation.

using the simulation, find min speed, max speed, time taken, distance travelled, as well as torque and acceleration at minimum RPM. In this case, torque at minimum RPM = 600Nm, and acceleration (found in the second graph) is 7.93N/kg = 7.93m/s^2. Call these values minS, maxS, t1, d1, T, A, respectively.

We can compute t2 = (maxS - minS)/(A/T * 100).

Then compute d2 = (maxS + minS)/2 * t2.

Then, just use the formula torque = 100 * (d2 - maxS*t2)/(d1 - t1*maxS) as explained earlier.


Overall, this is the closed form formula:
100 * ((maxS + minS)/2 * (maxS - minS)/(A/T * 100) - maxS*(maxS - minS)/(A/T * 100))/(d1 - t1*maxS)
It is very ugly, but at least you can cancel out the 100s, and you just get:
torque = ((maxS + minS)/2 * (maxS - minS)/(A/T) - maxS*(maxS - minS)/(A/T))/(d1 - t1*maxS)

First of all thank you. The flow on my calculators is like this. You input data and hit calculate. On that calculate it would be perfect if I could display also this equivalent constant engine torque.  To do that with your solution, I would need to recalculate again with 100 nm constant torque and then apply the formula. Question 1. In the example the gold/brown line is for the EQ 392 Nm simulation not for the real graph curve. What if the real torque graph will need  to wait at full speed for the constant torque graph? Will your formula work?(I don't know now if that is a posible scenario).

2nd question: Could I avoid the 2nd calculation for 100 nm constant torque to find the 391.8 Nm constant torque? Taking into account that 100 is constant maybe I cand get those values easily without needing to do a new full simulation.

FYI: I ran your formula on another random electric-like torque graph and the equivalent seems to be calculated ok. But still I need to make 2 calculations/simulations for it... I'll have a look to see how I can get d2 and t2 (a shortcut) without the second simulation. I'll keep you posted.

for your first question: Yes the formula will work. Notice that my formula finds a value of torque such that the curve ends on the extended brown line. If it ends below the real torque curve, then the constant torque curve will be extended and meet the real torque curve. If it ends above the real torque curve, then the real torque curve will be extended and meet the constant torque curve. @marius-ciclistu

Thank you. If I can't find that shortcut I'll have to display the calculated value only on comparison page when one of the calculations has constant torque + 1st gear is used on all its rpm range in both calculations + air friction is not taken into considerations in both calculations + the mass, wheels and gear ratios are the same in both calculations.

@marius-ciclistu I have made some sort of a shortcut where you can get all the information you need from only one simulation. I'm not sure if it achieves your goal though. Let me know.

@marius-ciclistu forgot to mention that i have edited the end of my answer with the new shortcut.

Thanks. I'll give it a try and come back. Atm I don't see the 100 Nm constant torque in the shortcut as you reference the 600 Nm start torque.

Or 600 is the new 100 nm constant?

@marius-ciclistu yes the shortcut does not use the 100Nm constant torque. It uses the relationship between acceleration and torque to calculate d2 and t2.

@marius-ciclistu no 600 is not the new 100Nm constant. It is the torque at minimum RPM. For the tesla, the minimum RPM is 1350, and when RPM = 1350, then the torque is set to 600Nm.

Ok. Could I use another arbitrary torque value or it must be first? First value I think is not so accurate. Or it must be the one from min speed?

@marius-ciclistu you can use any torque value but you have to use the corresponding value for acceleration. For example, at 10k RPM, you have a torque of 260Nm, so then you look at the value of acceleration at 10k RPM also. In this case, it is roughly 3.45m/s^2.

@marius-ciclistu also if you find my answer satisfactory do you think you could make it the answer for this question?

I will mark it as an answer once I code it and test it. I will reference the answer also in the calculator. Now I'm on phone.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thank you. I edited the question with the 2nd solution (codded).

Here's simple algebra demonstrating that the single equivalent acceleration is different for time to reach a velocity rather than distance to reach a velocity. The difference in this case is ~14%


I know. That is why the gold colored line is in the graphs. Constant top speed with 0 acceleration. It can be seen in the legend last row.

Added input data for gear ratio 10 picture in the question.
